# Getting BeanCreationException after upgrading spring-boot from 1.3 to 2.03

Tags: java, spring-boot

Getting this error after upgrading to 2.0.3.RELEASE of spring-boot-starter-parent. I have multiple repository interfaces extending JpaRepository from data-jpa.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xRepository': Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Comment: There is not enough information to provide a definitive answer, however the error message is suggesting the constructor for your bean does not exist.

Comment: @Allen Can you post the complete error trace and the details of the bean which is autowired ? Did you check whether the bean is correctly instantiated ?